# Error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL while processing big async loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I am experiencing a very strange problem. I am importing some big xml-files and store them into mongoDB. The algorythm is a typical async loop:

```
doLoop = function( it, callback_loop ) {
    if( it < no_of_items ) {
        storeToMongo( ..., function( err, result ) {
                ...
                doLoop( it+1, callback_loop );
        });
    } else {
        callback_loop();
    }
};
doLoop( 0, function() {
    ...
});
```

Now (suddenly without any remarkable change in the code) I get the following error while performing the loop:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at connect (net.js:764:19)
    at net.js:842:9
    at dns.js:72:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

The error happens after approximately a minute. The number of items processed in the meantime is always quite the same, but not exactly.

I tried to find out what `connect/net` causes the error, but I am lost. There is not socket-connection in my code. I have a connection to redis, but that is o.k. Is it the mongoDB-connection? But why does it get lost suddenly?

The only thing that helps to run through the whole loop is to perform the recursive loop call within the mongo-callback like this:

```
setTimeout( function() {
    doLoop( it+1, callback_loop );
},1);
```

Anyone out there who has an idea what is going wrong here?

Thanks,
heinob

Comment: Are you sure there is no other node is running same server?? try to grep the process

Comment: Yes, there is another node process running. But they did not disturb each other in the past. And why does the setTimeout-workaround "solve" the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I have found the answer. It is a problem within the default global http agent. See a full description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991551/eaddrnotavail-after-many-http-get-requests-to-localhost/20993398#20993398).

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with `process.nextTick` or `setImmediate` instead of the `setTimeout` - it's supposed to be [faster](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback).

As you do everything in one single event-loop tick I assume that some network buffer overflows. Maybe letting node `tick` shuffles away some of that buffer in your case.

As you already mentioned, it might also be due to simple overload of the "attacked" system.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use a write concern w:1 at least every couple of writes to ensure you don't flood the socket. Most likely you are doing writes with w:0 (unacknowledged writes) and just basically dumping all the data into the socket buffer until it overruns and shuts down or errors out.