# EADDRNOTAVAIL after many http.get requests to localhost

Tags: node.js, httprequest

When doing many http.get-requests to localhost (Apache) after 28233 requests I get `EADDRNOTAVAIL`.

When broken:

- I **cannot do** a http.request to localhost for (round about) 10 seconds (`EADDRNOTAVAIL`)

While *these 10 seconds*

- I **can do** `curl http://localhost`  (there is no error in Apache, it is still working like charm)
- I **can do**  a http.get-request (from node.js) to `www.google.com` (the error only affects requests to localhost)

After 10 seconds

- I **can do** a http.request to localhost again (as if node.js has healed itself)

This is the code:

```
var http = require( "http");

function httpRequest( callback ) {
    var options = {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 80,
            path: ''
        },
        data = "";

    http.get(options, function(resp){
        resp.on('data', function( chunk ){   
            data += chunk;
        }).on("end", function() {
            callback( null, data );
        });
    }).on("error", function(e){
            callback( e );
    });
}

function loop( i, callback ) {
    if( i < 100000 ) {
        httpRequest( function( err, data ) {
            if( err ) {
                console.log( "Error!", i, err );
                return;
            }
            if( i % 1000 === 0 ) {
                console.log( i );
            }
            loop( i+1, callback );
        });
    } else {
        callback();
    }
}

console.log( "GO!");
loop( 0, function() {
   console.log( "READY!");
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have found the solution by overwriting the default global agent. One possibility is to set `maxSockets:1`:

```
var http = require( "http"),
    agent = new http.Agent( {maxSockets: 1} ); // <-- this is new

function httpRequest( callback ) {
    var options = {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 80,
            path: '',
            agent: agent // <-- and this is new
        },
...
```

With this correction the example above works. But I **still had the EADDRNOTAVAIL issue** within my production code, so **setting the `agent` to `false` did it finally**:

```
var http = require( "http");

function httpRequest( callback ) {
    var options = {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 80,
            path: '',
            agent: false // <-- here
        },
...
```

I have posted this issue also on [GitHub](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6833).

Comment: Thanks. Setting the agent to false solve a related issue I had with the AWS SDK and DynamoDB connections. (Under some circumstances, periodically the requests took 25 seconds instead of 50ms and EADDRNOTAVAIL was thrown sporadically. The period may correspond to 28233 requests)

Comment: Even i faced the same issue. Thanks i saved my tons of time ... Cheers

Answer (score -2):

MacOS solution , or at least what worked for me[image]

and sending the request to mac.local