# How to send the maximal possible number of GET requests using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, http, get, request

My task is to send as much as possible GET requests using standart nodejs [http module](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) (with [http.get](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback)) to a remote server (for the data import, not DDOS :) ) But after a certain number of requests sending stops stop or go on very slowly.

I have already set the value `http.globalAgent.maxSockets = Infinity`, `req.setNoDelay(true);` and `req.setSocketKeepAlive(true);`. Also i make the requests in the [async queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) with 10-1000 concurrency and it affects the number of connections sent to a stop. I increased `ulimit -n` to a maximum.

Does somebody have advice or similar experience? Maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

See my appropriate node issues on [GitHub](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6833) and [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991551/eaddrnotavail-after-many-http-get-requests-to-localhost)

Maybe my workaround described there works for you too. Instead of modifying the globalAgent I disabled it.